# Indent execution results in zshell

Tags: shell, zsh

I'd like to customize my zshell so that the prompt is butted up against the left border like normal.  I'd also like to have all execution results indent by perhaps 2 spaces.  Is there a way to indent like this?

I'm experimenting with a 2-line prompt:

```
PROMPT='
%{$fg[gray]%}PWD:%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[cyan]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}
%{$fg[red]%}> '
```

It would be nice to make this prompt standout in its own column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not as straight forward as one might think. You have to intercept STDOUT, as external programs directly write to that channel.

The following is kind of a *proof of concept* . Be aware, that this will break a lot of things, namely interactive programs like `man`, `less` etc. So it's not usable for every-day-use, but to easily format a shell session for a post on e.g. SU.

This approach was posted by Atom Smasher on the `zsh-users` mailinglist on [Sat, 16 May 2009](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2009/msg00498.html) to colorize `STDERR`. I adopted it to your requirements:

```
# ## indent_output.zsh ##

zmodload zsh/terminfo zsh/system
autoload is-at-least

indent_output() {
  while sysread line
  do
    testline=${line//$'\n'/$'\n'   }
    syswrite "   ${testline}"      
  done
}

precmd() { sleep 0 }

## i'm not sure exactly how far back it's safe to go with this
## 4.3.4 works; 4.2.1 hangs.
is-at-least 4.3.4 && exec  > >(indent_output)
```

The tricky part is `exec  > >(indent_output)` which processes the complete output of the replacing shell through the `indent_output` function. The `precmd` definition is necessary to avoid a race condition, otherwise the new prompt is printed before the actual output of the executed command.

Here is a demo:

```
% source indent_output.zsh
% ls /bin | head
   [.exe
   2to3
   2to3-3.2
   411toppm.exe
   7z
   7za
   7zr
   a2p.exe
   aaflip.exe
   aclocal
   %
% date
   Sat, Nov 08, 2014  5:58:29 PM
   %
% cat /usr/share/doc/foo
   cat   :       /usr/share/doc/foo   :    No such file or directory   
   %
% cat /usr/share/doc/zsh-5.0.6/INSTALL| head
                           ++++++++++++++
                           INSTALLING ZSH
                           ++++++++++++++

   This file is divided into two parts:  making and installing the shell, a
   note on the script run to set up the environment for new users, and
   a description of various additional configuration options.  You should
   have a look at the items in the second and third parts before following the
   instructions in the first.

   %
%
```

You can get rid of the `%` sign before every prompt (which denotes that the last line does not end with `CR`) with these two options:

```
setopt PROMPT_CR NO_PROMPT_SP
```

Comment: Yes.  This gets me the indentation which offers a readability improvement.  I've been using it for a little while now and I can live with the way it (a) adds that funny `%` symbol to the bottom, (b) delivers man pages, and (c) pushes `ls` to a single column.  However, the loss of coloration for git output might be a deal breaker for me.

Comment: I've noticed that colorized output from `tree -CL 1` works but colorized output from `git status` or `git log` does not work.  Any ideas on how to get the color back for the git output?

Comment: @bholben: regarding (a) The `%` is because zsh detects that the last line does not end with `CR`, to suppress it use: `setopt PROMPT_CR NO_PROMPT_SP`. regarding git: use `color.ui=always` in your git config to force git to colorize output. But this probably breaks `git diff > patch-file`. You can also force ls to use colors: `ls --color=always`.

Comment: Great!  That cleans it up nicely.  I'll use this for a while and see how it affects my workflow.  I really like it.